# Auto refresh an iccube report

Tags: iccube-reporting

I want to refresh a reporting widget, either triggered by cube data update (server side) or triggered periodically (probably on the client side).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to refresh a full report (only available on Enterprise Real time).

There is a setting available in Configuration / Layout / Refresh Period field (advanced). This will ping the server each x seconds and if new date refresh the report accordingly.

hope it helps.